# Проблема с ивентом кнопки в Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Проблема в том,что у меня есть значение переменной sometxt, я хочу проверить совпадает ли оно со значением, которое я ввожу в entry. Каким образом это можно сделать не используя классов? Использую tkinter. Вот мой код:

```
      sometxt="Bee"
def Opentest(stxt):
    txt=stxt
    def output(event,txt):
        txt1=entry1.get()
        if txt1==txt:
            print("Nice")
    entry1=Entry(root)
    button=Button(root,text="Check")
    button.bind("<Button-1>",output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример:

```
in [12]: import tkinter as tk

In [12]: content = 'hello world'

In [13]: def Ex():
    ...:     root = tk.Tk()
    ...:     def active(event):
    ...:         if entry.get() == content:
    ...:             print('Yes')
    ...:     button = tk.Button(root, text='Сравнить')
    ...:     entry = tk.Entry(root)
    ...:     entry.pack()
    ...:     button.pack()
    ...:     button.bind('<Button-1>', active)
    ...:     root.mainloop()
```

Если ввести в поле `hello world`, вывод будет `Yes`

Answer (score 0):

Иногда удобно использовать [tkinter-переменные - StringVar](http://younglinux.info/book/export/html/54). Изменение значения такой переменной ведет к изменению и свойства виджета, и наоборот: изменение свойства виджета изменяет значение ассоциированной переменной. Получить/присвоить значение таким объектам можно с помощью методов `get` и `set`.

В следуюшем примере, `var.set()`, либо изменение текста в `Entry`, ведет к изменению всех объектов: `Button, Entry, var`.

```
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    var = tk.StringVar(root)
    var.set('Hello')  # присвоить

    tk.Button(root, textvariable=var).pack()
    tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var).pack()  # изменить

    root.mainloop()
    print(var.get())  # получить
```